# A fruitseller by means of a false balance cheats

Tags: elementary-number-theory

A fruitseller by means of a false balance cheats $20$% in buying fruits and also cheatz buyer to the same extent in selling. Find the gain percent on his outlay.

My attempt:

While buying $1$ kg,
$$=1+\frac{20}{100} \times 1$$
$$=\frac{6}{5}$$

While selling $1$ kg,
$$1-\frac{20}{100} \times 1$$
$$=\frac{4}{5}$$.

Now, what should I do next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets assume the original price to be $x$.

If the fruit seller was honest $$ 1 kg \rightarrow x $$
Since he cheats 20% while buying 
          $$ 1 kg \rightarrow 4x/5 $$
Also he cheats 20% while selling
          $$ 1 kg \rightarrow 6x/5 $$
His net profit is
          $$ 6x/5 - 4x/5 = 2x/5 $$
Gain percent is (Profit/Cost Price)*100
          $$ \frac{2x/5}{4x/5}*100 = 50\% $$
His gain percent is 50%

Comment: actually the answer in my book is 44%?